# How to Redirect 301 URL with .php in it

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I am unable to redirect some URLs with an .php in it, for example:

```
Redirect 301 /hotel-buchen/wellnesshotel.php/hotel/package-detail.php?id=43345&parent=list&pension_id=281#/cst-book-10 /wellnessurlaub/online-buchen/#/package-detail.php?id=43345&parent=list&pension_id=281#/cst-book-10
```

Can someone explain how to propertly redirect URLs like this?

Comment: have you tried removing the whitespace in the middle ?

Comment: What have you tried before asking it on SO?

Comment: You cannot match query string using `Redrect`. Use `RewriteCond` of `mod`_rewrite`

Comment: I have already tried everthing the URL´s rederict not correct... antother example: 

Redirect 301 /hotel/wellnessurlaub.php/bernkastel-kues/blackvip-im-wellnesshotel-zum-kurfuersten /kontakt-infomationen/service/black-vip/

It Rederict me to /kontakt-infomationen/service/hotel-faqs-von-a-z//nachhaltigkeit

Comment: Or /wellnesshotel.php/fotogalerie rederict to //fotogalerie